# Rails Devise timeoutable does not reload page even if AJAX request fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Devise gem for authentication. I have used timeoutable feature of devise to redirect to login page if no user activity seen for specified time. The issue is mainly when ajax request is sent and session timed out, the UI becomes nonresponsive. Below is my configuration:
In User model:

```
devise :timeoutable

def timeout_in
  if self.role.name == "Admin"
   30.minutes
  end
end
```

This does the timeout(session expires after 30 mins if no user activity is seen). But it does not autorefresh page to show the signin page. I have even tried to use javascript that does the regular check if session has expired or not and if expired, just reload the page mainly for ajax request in order to avoid unresponsive UI. But this does not work either. Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Whenever AJAX request encounters a 401 i.e., Unauthorized token error, refresh/ reload the page :

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax({
            url: "/validate_barcode",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {barcode: barcode},
            }).done(function (data,status,jqXHR) {
              console.log("Success");
            }).fail(function (jqXHR,status,err) {
              // alert("Promise error callback.");
              if(jqXHR.status == 401){
                location.reload();
              }
            })
```

This worked and reloaded the page to show login screen if session timedout and UI became non responsive.

Comment: Strange; I've tried implementing this on my end - having a timer that implements an ajax ping and does the redraw if it gets a 401 return -- but of course that keeps the connection alive.  Not sure how best to implement.